# What automatic code generation tools are available for Castle ActiveRecord classes?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, code-generation, castle-activerecord

If I have an existing database, I want to be able to automatically code generate the corresponding Castle ActiveRecord C# classes based on the db schema. My primary intent is to avoid manually creating each class.  What are my options for code gen tools with templates that can already specifically do this for Castle ActiveRecord?

(Note: This question is not about codegen tools in general. I am looking for tools specific to Castle ActiveRecord or have codegen templates already written for ActiveRecord.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327146/how-to-generate-castle-activerecord-c-classes-for-an-existing-database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/ActiveWriter and http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/  Both are free.

Comment: ActiveWriter is not template based.

Answer (score 0):

And this one that's written for Castle ActiveRecord:
  http://roytate.blogspot.com/2007/07/castle-active-record-code-generator.html